# Why does kivy work with python 3.5, but not 3.6?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, python3, kivy

When I run python3.6 in the terminal I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "app_with_kv.py", line 14, in 
>       import kivy
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

When I run python3.5 in the terminal there is no problem, why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: How did you install kivy?

Comment: I installed using the instructions on their website.

Comment: kivy is in the system path for 3.5 but not  in the system path for 3.6 .. ie you installed it for 3.5 but not for 3.6.

Comment: How do install it to the path for 3.6

Comment: I went through kivy documentation and and package info and found out kivy doesn't support 3.6 yet. It only supports up to 3.5.